# abstract messes up formatting

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

I'm writing a paper using the article document class. I have an abstract at the beginning of the paper and this seems to mess up my formatting, for example, I have

```
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
```

With the abstract, the paragraphs indent, but when I comment out the abstract, it reverts to the formatting I want.  There is other formatting, for example text height and width changes, which disappears when I include the abstract.  Does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) If you have a problem with your code, we need to know that code to be able to help you. So please add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your question, that can be used to reproduce the problem. Without such a MWE your question is somehow unclear. So please help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Doh!!  I figured out the problem, I was using

```
\abstract{this is the abstract.}
```

and changed it to

```
\begin{abstract}this is the abstract.\end{abstract}
```

This seems to have fixed it.  The funny thing is that the first way created an abstract and did not give an error message.

Comment: `\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}` is equivalent to `\abstrac ... \endabstract` so ....

Comment: this is a very frequent error (I was just about to post that as a guessed answer without even seeing your document). it is a general feature that use of the begin code of an environment does not cause an error, consider `\center{abc}` which acts in the same way